# Pandas: Sort value and ignore 0

Tags: python, pandas, sorting, dataframe

I've following data:

```
product profit
a   32
b   43
c   23
d   34
e   0
f   0
g   -14
h   -12
i   -9
j   -8
k   -3
```

I want to sort values and ignore the zero.

```
df.sort_values(by="profit", ascending=False)
```

The expected output should be:

```
product profit
b   43
d   34
a   32
c   23
k   -3
j   -8
i   -9
h   -12
g   -14
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can chain masks and operations with `pandas`:

```
df = df[df['profit'] != 0].sort_values('profit', ascending=False)
```

Or, for readability, you have at least a couple more options:

**Operator chaining**

```
df = df.loc[df['profit'] != 0]\
       .sort_values('profit', ascending=False)
```

**Mask + sort**

```
mask = df['profit'] != 0
df = df[mask].sort_values('profit', ascending=False)
```

Comment: Yes you can. I however prefer to create an extra mask variable or separate the operations for readability. It is a matter of preference but the pythonic way strives for easy comprehension after all. Your solution surpasses pep 8 79 columns. The aaproach u use is unquestionable though.